# Halliday Resnick and Krane chapter 1, problem 2 part C. Can't understand instructor's solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, units

I understand how to solve this question but I don't understand the solution in the instructors manual for part c.
The question is:

The average distance of the Sun from the Earth is 390 times
the average distance of the Moon from the Earth. Now consider a total eclipse of the Sun (Moon between Earth and Sun;
) and calculate (a) the ratio of the Sun’s diameter
to the Moon’s diameter, and (b) the ratio of the Sun’s volume
to the Moon’s volume. (c) The angle intercepted at the eye by
the Moon is 0.52° and the distance between the Earth and the
Moon is 3.82 * 105 km. Calculate the diameter of the Moon.

The solution in the instructor's manual is:

0.52◦
(2π/360◦
) = 9.1 × 10−3
rad. The diameter is then (9.1 × 10−3
rad)(3.82 × 105 km) =
3500 km.

What I don't understand is why he didn't need to take the tan() of 9.1 × 10−3 rad after converting it from degrees to radians. If my understanding is correct, shouldn't it be, tan((9.1 × 10−3 rad))(3.82 × 105 km)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try punching $\tan(9.1\times 10^{-3})$ into your calculator (making sure you're in radian mode) and see how much it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Arc length is given by $l=r\theta$ and $\theta$ is in radians ($r$ is the average distance to the moon).

And the writer certainly could have done it the way you suggest, but note: $$\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}=\frac{\frac 12\text{moon diameter}}{3.82\times 10^5\text{km}}$$ So $$\text{moon diameter}=2\times 3.82\times 10^5\times \tan(0.26^\circ)=3,466\text{ km}$$ making the diameter of the moon $\approx 3500\text{ km}$ which is consistent with the first method.

So it is not $(\tan\theta^R\times r)$ but instead $(\theta^R\times r)$

Comment: Why is is it tan(θ/2)) and not tan(θ)?

Comment: Because the opposite length is the radius not the diameter.

Comment: What radius? Isn't the adjacent the distance and the opposite the diameter?

Comment: No. The adjacent is the distance, but the opposite is half the diameter as I have taken half the angle. I can't use the whole angle, because it would not be a right triangle anymore. I could have just written $\tan(0.26)$=radius of moon/distance. Make sense?

Comment: Ohhhh now I get it, thank you for your help :)

Comment: That's okay. Good luck with your studies.